# What is your favorite cross-platform solution to access multiple different databases (MySQL, Oracle...) in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, database, cross-platform

I am writing a simple C++ application which might be installed on Linux or Windows, and which will connect to a database.  I want my application to be compatible at least with Oracle and MySQL (or PostgreSQL).

Which C or C++ library would you recommend to handle the database queries: I am open to any library, whether it's very thin (just execute SQL queries) or very fat (a whole object persistence layer, clustering, etc.).

One library per answer, please. A little description (pros & cons) would be great.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I enjoy using [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/), it's very C++ like. When it comes to performance with respect to Oracle database, it's comparable with native OCI. It provides backend to some RDBMS:

- Oracle
- PostgreSQL
- MySQL

And some more in the CVS repository.

It's fairly simple to use, the documentation is thorough and rationale is pretty clear. It supports connection pooling, has nice extensible way of converting between datatypes.

Comment: Very nice!  I didn't know about that one.  I'll wait a day or two before I accept your answer to see if other suggestions are comparable, but so far this is the best option for my project.  Thanks a lot.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

I really liked [QtSql](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-index.html)

- It has the advantage of being well designed and cross platform.
- Disadvantage is that it's LGPLv3 (or commercial) licensed and that might not work for everybody.

You don't have to use a Qt GUI, but if you need a GUI library too it's wonderful.

Comment: Interesting insight, thanks.  I appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what [ODBC](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110093) was designed for. Yes, it was designed by Microsoft, but there are implementations on just about every platform and for just about every database product now.

Comment: Yes, I saw ODBC and unixODBC, but I felt it was pretty heavy-weight, and I have found that it impacts performance quite a bit.  Would you agree?

Comment: I wouldn't touch ODBC unless I had to...

Answer (score 1):

I use SQLAPI++ and it's a great product.  You can try it for free, it's simple to get started and their support is fantastic.

http://www.sqlapi.com/

Comment: Looks good.  Too bad it's not Open Source, but the price looks reasonable. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously?  [Data Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972319.aspx).

Nothing beats customizing your data calls for each database.  Generic solutions tend to have too many compromises IMO.

Comment: It's the lowest common denominator syndrome.

Comment: Yes, my app really doesn't need to do much.  I haven't read your link yet, but it looks like it requires .NET?  Isn't there anything lighter than that?  I took a look at ODBC & unixODBC, but it's also a bit heavyweight for what I want to do (basically list tables and count rows!).

Comment: No, it doesn't require .NET.  It's a pattern that is used frequently in .NET but can be applied to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you would be wise to stay away from data provider API as time goes , you will suffer versioning and default parametrisation issues. Best would be to use SOCI when you really need full optimized backend otherwise stick to any facilitator like OTL4.0 for ODBC call.